# How to clear a background image when switching images in android

Tags: android, background-image, imagebutton

I have a button which switches between 2 images depending on the number of clicks...sometimes I get after leaving the activity and returning, both images show. How do make sure that only 1 image is showing?

Here is the code for the swap:

```
public void swapImageButton() {
    swapCount ++;
    if(swapCount % 2 == 0) {
        mStomachImageButton.setBackground(getDrawable(image1));
        mFartImageButton.setBackground(getDrawable(image2));
    } else {
        mStomachImageButton.setBackground(getDrawable(image2));
        mFartImageButton.setBackground(getDrawable(image1));
    }
}
```

Comment: you should try image switcher

Comment: if you want to clear background than set `img.setImageBitmap(null);`

Comment: use flags with sharedpreferences

Comment: Thanks guys...Akash's was a simple fix!

Comment: @fmi welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a static variable for count.

```
static int count=0;

public void swapImageButton() {

    if(count == 0) {
       //show you image when clicked first time
        count=1;
    } else {
        //show you image when clicked second time
        count=0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The two best ways to save the state of the control are:

- Save the "swapCount" in bundle. Check [Activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html)
- [Preferences](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) for your activity where you can save the "swapCount"

I would go with the bundle, but that requires understanding the lifecycle of an activity. Btw, avoid the static variable idea.